# Acer Nitro 5 touchpad and keyboard are not working during Ubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation, 19.04, acer

I am trying to install Ubuntu 19.04 but my [Acer Nitro 5 with a GTX-1050Ti](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/NH.Q3YAA.001) touchpad as well as the keyboard isn't working. But the cursor moves fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing what options are available in the BIOS that relate to the touchpad and keyboard. Usually you can open the BIOS on Acer machines by pressing the F2 or the Delete key during startup. There might be an option to change from "Advanced" to "Basic" or "PS/2". If so, you could try changing this and see if you have any luck back in Ubuntu.